# Pass HTML markup into Vue.js Swiper carousel component

Tags: vue.js, swiper.js

I have a working carousel running using the Swiper Vue.js component, but I'm trying to figure out how to markup the slides in my html page rather than within the Vue component. I'm a bit of a novice with Vue and probably lacking some fundamentals so may be way off. I've been looking at using slots but haven't managed to figure anything out yet.

This is what I currently have working:

**SwiperCarousel.vue**

```html
<template>
  <swiper
    :slides-per-view="3"
    :space-between="50"
    @swiper="onSwiper"
    @slideChange="onSlideChange"
  >
    <swiper-slide>
      <img src="img01.jpg">
      <caption>Caption 01</caption>
    </swiper-slide>

    <swiper-slide>
      <img src="img02.jpg">
      <caption>Caption 02</caption>
    </swiper-slide>

  </swiper>
</template>
```

But I'd like to be able to do something like this:

**HTML**

```html
<div id="app">
  <swiper-carousel>

    <div class="slide01">
      <img src="img01.jpg">
      <caption>Caption 01</caption>
    </div>

    <div class="slide02">
      <img src="img02.jpg">
      <caption>Caption 02</caption>
    </div>

  </swiper-carousel>
</div>
```

Hope that makes sense, thanks.

Comment: Not sure if I understood the question correctly, but it sounds like you are trying to mount a Vue app/component into a html element.

Comment: No worries, I struggled to explain it. The other way around I think. I want to populate my component with the slides html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got this sorted now, I think the confusion was because I was creating a single file component `SwiperCarousel.vue` which contained the `Swiper` and `SwiperSlide` components. I've got rid of `SwiperCarousel.vue` and just using the other two components directly in the HTML.

**App.vue**

```js
<script>
import SwiperCore, { Navigation, Pagination, A11y } from "swiper";

// Import Swiper Vue.js components
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/vue";

// install Swiper components
SwiperCore.use([Navigation, Pagination, A11y]);

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    Swiper,
    SwiperSlide,
  },
  methods: {
    onSwiper(swiper) {
      console.log(swiper);
    },
    onSlideChange() {
      console.log("slide change");
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

**HTML**

```html
<swiper 
  :slides-per-view="3" 
  :space-between="50" 
  navigation="navigation" 
  :pagination="{ clickable: true }"
  @swiper="onSwiper" 
  @slidechange="onSlideChange"
>
  <swiper-slide>Slide 01</swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide>Slide 02</swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide>Slide 03</swiper-slide>
</swiper>
```

Thanks for the comments.